# make multiple http post in android

Tags: java, android

hello i want to ask some question
i want to make application that connected with a web services that i made

my app has 2 uniqueID called app_id and token, app_id generate only once when the app first start and token generated by web service

every request, i must check whenever the token already expired or not, if the token already expired it will call separate web service and generate new token

the problem is the app must access 2 different web service: to request new token and to get another desired data

i use asynctask, but the response from web service for request token always same every request and i have no idea why

```
protected Boolean doInBackground(Void... params) {
        int status = 0;
        int token_expired=0;
        String token_val = token.getToken(getBaseContext());
        for(int i=0;i<5 && status==0;i++) {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(1000);
                //function to check if token already expired or not and request new token using http post
                token_expired = token.checkToken(getBaseContext());
                System.out.println("token expired: " +token_expired);
                if (token_expired==1 || token_expired==2) {
                     //function to call another web service and get a data from it
                     status =  rclient.Execute("POST");
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        if (status==0) {
            return false;
        }else{
            return true;
        }
    }
```

thanks before!

Comment: where is your code for expired token functionality?

Comment: i post my other function below

Answer (score 0):

oh yeah this is a function of check token from class token handler

```
public Integer checkToken(Context context) {
        int status = 0; //0 = failed to request token , 1 = successfully request new token, 2 = token has not expired yet
        String token_id = getToken(context); 
        System.out.println("token_id: " +token_id);
        //if (token_id!=null) {
            Long time = getTime(context);
            Long curr_time = System.currentTimeMillis()/1000;
            System.out.println("time before: " +time);
            System.out.println("time current: " +curr_time);
            Long interval = curr_time - time;
            System.out.println("interval: " +interval);
            if (interval>10) {
                status = TokenGenerator(context);
            }else {
                status = 2;
            }       
        //}
        return status;      
    }

}
```

and this is a function to request new token from the same class

```
    public synchronized Integer TokenGenerator(Context context) {
     int status = 0;
     SharedPreferences sharedPrefs = context.getSharedPreferences(TOKEN_STORAGE, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
     uniqueID = sharedPrefs.getString(PREF_UNIQUE_ID, null);
     try {
        rclient.AddJSON("app_id", uniqueID);
        rclient.CompileJSON();
    } catch (JSONException e1) {
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }
     try {
        status =  rclient.Execute("POST");
     } catch (Exception e) {
         e.printStackTrace();
     } 
     if (status==1) {
        String response = rclient.getResponse();
        String token = null;
        System.out.println("uuid_response: " +response);
        try {
            JSONObject json = new JSONObject(response);
            token = json.getString("result");
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        Long tsLong = System.currentTimeMillis()/1000;
        String ts = tsLong.toString();
        System.out.println("time: " +ts);
        Editor editor = sharedPrefs.edit();
        editor.putString(TIMESTAMP, ts);
        editor.putString(TOKEN_ID, token);
        editor.commit();
        }
return status;

}
```

so basically the rest client class called two times, first at class token handler to request a new token, and second from the activity itself

Answer (score 0):

As per the code posted by you, I think rclient.Execute("POST") is used to get the data. But the below piece of code

```
if (token_expired==1 || token_expired==2) {
     //function to call another web service and get a data from it
     status =  rclient.Execute("POST");
}
```

says that if the token is still alive you are trying to get the new token again.
I think the line status =  rclient.Execute("POST"); should be replaced with the code to fetch the data from the server.

Answer (score 0):

problem solved after i put constructor of rest client class in function